# How to use Facebook messenger api in react native

Tags: facebook, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I am using react-native-fbsdk to use Facebook APIs in my react native project. I am able to implement login/share/logout functionalities using this but till now haven't found any way to use Facebook messenger APIs.

Is there any way I can integrate FB messenger API in a react native project using this library?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with FB messenger API  ?

Comment: @WizKid The precise use case I am looking for is this
There is a messenger icon on my app, when the user taps on it it opens the messenger ui. The user can select whom he wants to send the content/message to and send it from my app itself. Basically i don't want to use the Android share widget or iOS share sheet for this.

Comment: Use the send dialog. There is no other API

Comment: @WizKid How to use send dialog in react native?

Comment: @RohitGoyal Did you find a workaround ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to do it with [React Native's Linking](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking):

```
Linking.openURL(`fb-messenger://share?link=${sharingUrl}`);
```

where `sharingUrl` is the link you want to attach.

**Result**

This will open Messenger app with the attached link and the user will be able to add a message to it and send it to his friends. (Caution: nothing will happen if the user does not have Messenger installed.)

Prefilling a message seems impossible however.

See the [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog/)

Comment: if I want to send message to business page, how to use it with Linking.openURL(`fb-messenger://

Comment: Have u found the solution? @Manspof ?